# Capybara: How to set files names and directory for save_and_open_page_path

Tags: ruby, rspec, automation, automated-tests, capybara

I am trying to set the directory where all screens shots will be saved. Because currently it saves to the root folder, but I would like to save files (.img and .html) to another one folder. I tried to use

```
CapybaraScreenshot.save_and_open_page_path = "../Reports"
```

or

```
CapybaraScreenshot.save_and_open_page('../Reports')
```

But it still saves screenshots and .html files to root directory(((

Also may be it is possible to set screen shot name as TC name, because currently it is unclear which screen shot related to proper failed TC.

Here is my rails_helper.rb file:

```
require 'test/unit'
require 'selenium-webdriver'
require 'capybara'
require 'rspec'
require "rails/all"
require 'capybara/rspec'
require "page-object"
require 'rspec/expectations'
require 'securerandom'
require '../Test_helpers/login_helper'
require 'capybara-screenshot/rspec'
require 'launchy'

RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.include LoginHelper
  config.include RSpec::Matchers
  config.include Capybara::DSL

  Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = '../Resources/chromedriver.exe'
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
  end

  config.after { |example_group| CapybaraScreenshot.save_and_open_page_path = '../Reports' if example_group.exception }

end
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 15
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented in the capybara-screenshot README - https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot#custom-screenshot-directory and https://github.com/mattheworiordan/capybara-screenshot#custom-screenshot-filename , you need to set Capybara.save_path (just specify it once, not in an after block) for the directory and use Capybara::Screenshot.register_filename_prefix_formatter to override the file name used

Comment: @SerhiiKaihorodov You're welcome - don't forget to accept an answer so the question gets marked as answered

Answer (score 1):

I did it as following (Thanks @Tom Walpole):

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.include LoginHelper
  config.include RSpec::Matchers
  config.include Capybara::DSL

  Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.driver_path = '../Resources/chromedriver.exe'
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
  end

  Capybara.save_path = "../Reports"

  config.after { |example_group| CapybaraScreenshot.save_and_open_page_path if example_group.exception }

  Capybara::Screenshot.register_filename_prefix_formatter(:rspec) do |example|
    "screenshot_#{example.description.gsub(' ', '-').gsub(/^.*\/spec\//,'')}"
  end

end
```

Comment: Just a note for Minitest users that you can do this by adding the same line in ```application_system_test_case.rb``` under the ApplicationSystemTestCase class.